# Setting font in share intent android

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am looking for the solution since quite a while now. I want to set the font of the text shared from my app to other apps.

I don't know how I can achieve this, the font is in .ttf file. The below code I am using but it is for the plain text.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<b>This is a message for you</b><br/>Hello");

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

Please let me know the possible options I have.

Thanks,
Amandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to set the font of the text shared from my app to other apps.

That is not possible, sorry.

> The below code I am using but it is for the plain text.

You may wish to use `text/html`, not `text/plain`, given that you are passing HTML tags.